# Search for fields other than title in Sitefinity backend dynamic module search

Tags: search, content-management-system, backend, upgrade, sitefinity

In sitefinity version 8.2 there was an option to search within dynamic module items by full name in the backend. But it is not giving any result after my upgrade to 12.2. Is this feature still available or should I need to enable it anywhere in the settings? I couldn't find any documentation related to that.
The search is working only for the title. Our application was in Sitefinity 8 and recently upgraded to 12.2.
Need some help with this.

Comment: what do you mean by "full name" ? is this a field of your dynamic module? Also, are you using the new backend UI (AdminApp) or still the classic one?

Comment: Hi Veselin, yes full name is a field in the dynamic module. Also, we are using the new UI  in admin app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the new backend UI (AdminApp) searches only by Title field.

A few workarounds are offered here:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/adminapp-searching-in-the-backend-works-on-title-field-only

The easiest of which is switching back to the classic (old) UI.